# RESTful API design

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest

Where to get started if I want to design a web service with RESTFul API? Any built-in support from .Net Framework or any 3rd party tool recommend?

Comment: WCF isn't really restful.  Its SOAP based...

Comment: @jfar - ever heard of WCF REST? (or OData even)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I absolutely love [OpenRasta](http://trac.caffeine-it.com/openrasta)!

I tried the REST support in WCF and was quickly turned off from it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

If your service is going to expose an information from a database, it's very simple to implement OData RESTful service (aka WCD Data Service) using WCF and Entity Framework.

Have a look at [this blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingAnODataAPIForStackOverflowIncludingXMLAndJSONIn30Minutes.aspx) by Scot Hanselman. He shows how you can create an OData service for StackOverflow.

Comment: I just want to a general Restful service? Can I implement using http handler?